# Why must you clear UK immigration when connecting to Ireland in spite of Irish border checks?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, ireland, common-travel-area

When flying from the UK to Ireland, you'll clear immigration at the Irish airport.

So why must people connecting in the UK clear immigration (and be photographed at security to prove they did this, rather than using the transit corridor) in order to board a flight to Ireland?

Is it to prevent non-Europeans from entering Ireland posing as Brits by presenting a UK driving licence, and then fly back to the UK (as you don't clear immigration in the other direction)?

Comment: Have you examined, or studied, "Operation Gull"? It is still in effect and is likely to remain in effect for long time.

Comment: @GayotFow I thought that pertained to Northern Irish air and ferryports

Comment: Yes, Belfast and all international ports in southern England.

Comment: @GayotFow Ah K, so once you present yourself at the UK border (say at Gatwick) and declare that you're going to Ireland, Operation Gull kicks in?

Comment: Yes, but *sporadically*, nobody knows how many people are assigned to the operation, but it cannot be discounted. What does kick off *every time* is the 2013 UK/US agreement (which the ROI also signed). So take your pick.

Comment: Unrelated, but tangentially useful, this is also linked in the archives as a US/Canada agreement entering force at about the same time. http://www.treaty-accord.gc.ca/text-texte.aspx?id=105246  I assume you are OK and don't need a formal answer.

Comment: @GayotFow Yep, all good!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64567/discussion-between-gayot-fow-and-crazydre).

Comment: You wouldn't even need to fly back, you could just go to a service desk, present yourself as a domestic-originating passenger who no longer wishes to fly to DUB, and ask to leave the airport. A photo match will be done against your boarding pass and you are free to go. If you set this up correctly, it would be very hard (or impossible) to distinguish you from a domestic-originating pax (perhaps one who came to this airport on a domestic flight from another terminal on a different ticket) who, of course, need not carry a passport to go to Ireland.

Comment: @Calchas If you try this loophole with the current System, and lack papers to enter UK, what would happen when going through the transit corridor with a boarding pass to DUB and then asking to leave the airport? Once they find out your photo wasn't taken? Would the ground staff call the Border Force and have them deal with the passenger?

Comment: @Crazydre Your photo would have been taken immediately post-passports. But that is a good question.

Comment: @JonathanReez it was resolved in chat IIRC and Crazydre has summarised the chat session.  At least somewhat. Partial, no links, in-a-hurry.   I'll abstain from voting to see if his answer is more conclusive with successive edits. Thanks for the courtesy of bring this question to my attention..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of this stems from [Operation Gull](http://www.lawcentreni.org/policy/policy-briefings/203.html), which is in place on a non-systematic basis at English airports as well as Northern Irish air- and seaports.

It is a measure to identify people intending to use the Common Travel Area (a British-Irish semi-open border concept) as a loophole to enter the republic of Ireland, as border controls at the land border are limited to spot checks on the motorway and trains between Belfast and Dublin.